# Print variable of same datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for to print two variables  of same datatype I have something like this

```
declare @one int ,@two int
set @one=1
set @two=2
print @one+@two
```

obviously it will give a result 3 but 
I need result 1 2

On search I got to convert the any one of these variable and come up this query.

```
print convert(varchar(10),@one)+@two
```

but the result was same 3!! 
What should I do,to get the result?
NB :I am using sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there... Just put a space between them (as that's how you want them to be formatted):

```
declare @one int ,@two int
set @one=1
set @two=2
print convert(varchar(10),@one)+' '+convert(varchar(10),@two)
```

Different datatypes:

```
declare @one int ,@two varchar(20)
set @one=1
set @two='zomgwtfbbq'
print convert(varchar(10),@one)+' '+@two;
```

Comment: Thanks phil ,but here you have converted both ,it that means i can't do with one datatype as int and the other as varchar

Comment: @Bijujose - Your question is about two integers.

Comment: I was wondering myself... Edited the answer with an example anyway

Comment: @phil-So if the datatypes are same like int you need to  convert it into varchar and if its different change any one of them to varchar am I right OR you should always convert all of them to  varchar type in print command(except varchar datatype)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) instead of `PRINT`. With a severity of 0 the two are equivalent but there is some primitive string formatting functionality available as below.

```
RAISERROR('%d %d',0,1,@one, @two)
```

Comment: ,it works fine,is there any good reason using raiserror instead of print

Comment: Because print doesn't support the placeholder `%d` syntax (you would use `%s` for a string BTW)

Comment: You can also use `WTIH NOWAIT` so that your `PRINT` commands aren't subject to Management Studio's output buffer limitations (in longer scripts you won't see your `PRINT` commands occurring in real time, the output will barf out a bunch of them at a time).